# Is there a tool can search a page and all linked css and js files for a string?

Tags: javascript

In my quest for knowledge I sometimes find myself scouring the source of a page only to find that the javascript method im looking for isnt on the page directly. That said I think it must be on one of the linked javascript pages. However I dont really want to have to look through each individual file to find the line. Is there a tool that can do this for me?

Preferably in firefox as an add-on I  was thinking...

Cheers,
Pete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked out [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

yes.. Firebug in Firefox | IE developer toolbar for IE | Developer toolbar for Firefox are great tools for indepth check of JS/CSS/HTML

Answer (score 0):

We ran into a similar challenge while developing/editing our WordPress sites (i.e. not being able to search all CSS/PHP/JS files at once). As a solve, we built a plugin to allow us to do just that. If this question is related to a WordPress site, the plugin might help - rather than searching in Firebug and then having to jump back onto WordPress, you can search all and edit directly in WordPress. Plugin is called [WP Backend File Search](https://www.wpbackendfilesearch.com/).